# Getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException with msg "Load factor needs to be between 0.1 and 1.0" while enumerating instances of PerformanceCounterCategory

Tags: c#, performancecounter, load-factor

I am trying to enumerate all instance names for a `PerformanceCounterCategory` by using `PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()` method and getting below exception:

```
Load factor needs to be between 0.1 and 1.0.
Parameter name: loadFactor
EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
   at System.Collections.Hashtable..ctor(Int32 capacity, Single loadFactor)
   at System.Diagnostics.CategorySample..ctor(Byte[] data, CategoryEntry entry, PerformanceCounterLib library)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(String categoryName, String machineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()
   at Abc.Xyz.Utilities.PerfCounter.InitCounter()
```

I already checked for Performance counter category and it exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at this https://rtroywest.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/hashtable-constructor-throwing-an-exception/ it's possibly an issue to do with .net 2 mixed with unmamaged code in some scenarios, are you usong .net 2?

Comment: Thanks @KMoussa , This is good information. But I tried the solution mentioned in the article but it didn't help.

Comment: Hi KMoussa. I'm the guy who wrote the blog post mentioned. I'm surprised this hasn't been fixed in the dotnet runtime yet. Are you using a newish version, or still DotNet 2? You say you tried the solution of putting calls to unmanaged code in its own thread - How did you do that? Don't use the threadpool. Crreate your own thread. Also, are you sure you have the correct unmanaged code? It will show up in the stack trace of every exception.